# ShowTypingMiddleware sending typing activities after response is sent to user by the bot

Tags: c#, botframework

I have created a v4 Bot Framework SDK (C#) based bot. And I am using the two middleware inside the adapter which are in same order -

```
 public AdapterWithErrorHandler(ICredentialProvider credentialProvider,
                                       BotConfigurationSettings configuration,
                                       IUtility utility,
                                       BotStateSet botStateSet,
                                       ConversationState conversationState = null)
               : base(credentialProvider)
        {
            // Show Typing Middleware
            Use(new ShowTypingMiddleware(1000, 2000));

            // Auto Save State Middleware
            Use(new AutoSaveStateMiddleware(botStateSet));
         }
```

The problem is that typing middleware send the typing activity sometimes intermittently and sometimes more frequently after a message is sent to the user and displayed in bot window.
But the side effect of this behavior is that it looks like bot typing another response but then typing indicator disappears.
This is very well reflected when I see that Dependency Call is cancelled in Application Insights.

I have tried to add custom delay and period values, but noting much happens.
Use(new ShowTypingMiddleware(1000, 2000));

I assume the reason might be AutoSaveStateMiddleware is trying to save conversation state and typing middleware is supposed to send activity after a period of delay but soon state is saved and then typing activity is cancelled.

I want to know how we can fix this behaviour.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. I spun up a bot with both of those middlewares and after each message I send, I get a typing activity. Note, also, that `ShowTypingMiddleware` is triggered when a **user** sends a message. If the bot isn't coded to respond to that message, the typing indicator will show and then disappear. Can you send a link to your code and steps to reproduce?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/2138)

Comment: @mdrichardson, thanks for the repro. I get activity when user sends the message while bot is composing a response from QnA and sends back. The problem is that after response is sent on webchat another typing indicator pops up and get cancelled in few moments. I have checked the reference link and I am using botadapter.use( middleware) method.

Comment: I'm still unable to replicate this. Are you able to share your full code (link to repo or send to email in my profile)?

Comment: I could not share full code due to confidentiality, but I suspect one thing that inside my bot.cs file OnTurnAsync method `// Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
            await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);` I had these lines of code generated from template. And I also had AutoSaveStateMiddlware which also saves state in each turn. From telemetry it looked like two cosmos db operations to save state async causing typing activity.

Comment: @mrichardson, please read above comment and if possible see if this can attribute the typing indicator being sent again due to delay in performing operations. One more thing I wanted to ask that I am using Confirm Prompt Dialog with a small message and often times the message comes first in bubble then typing indicator and then confirm buttons. This behaviour looks little off from user experience. Can you please suggest if there is any possibility to remedy this?

Comment: I agree that the double-save is likely causing performance issues that lead to the typing indicator "bug". You'd have to remove those lines and test to be sure. Regarding the Confirm Prompt, can you share that bit of code? That does sound odd since the typing indicator is supposed to show after received messages, not prior to sending them.

Comment: @mdrichardson, This is code of a waterfall dialog step that sends the confirm prompt - `private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ConversationContinueAnswerAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var message = stepContext.Options.ToString();
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ConfirmPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(message) }, cancellationToken);
        }` When prompt is sent to user the message is displayed and then confirm buttons popup. Seen this behaviour on both emulator & webchat.

Comment: I still can't seem to replicate this with the code you included (except I replaced `message` with `"message"` - [see recording](https://gfycat.com/amazingminiaturecaterpillar). Without more of your code, I don't believe I can help much more.

Comment: I think you need to see the behaviour on webchat control to see the real effects. Emulator might not really be displaying the true behaviour. I had been using webchat-0.11.3 because I made efforts to customize certain parts of it. Or you can use any other webchat version if it will be quick for you.

Comment: I was using one of the [WebChat Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). Note: Emulator also uses WebChat. I think the old version might be your issue.

Comment: I see this happening in MS Teams where the typing indicator either keeps running or re-starts after the response. I only save state one time, in the `OnTurnAsync` override, after calling `base.OnTurnAsync`.